# How to display OpenOffice error details

Tags: openoffice-calc

So after few years I had to use open office once again. It's just as fun as it always used to be.

I tried very simple expression [`LEFT(C1, 1)`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LEFT_function) which is supposed to pick first character from cell `C1`. What I get is [error 508](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes), which is "Error: Pair missing".

How can I get more info about what causes the error? I'm not aware of any missing parenthesis.

I tried to click on buttons in `Tools->Detective` but they are probably not doing anything. Maybe in next version?

Answer (score 1):

OpenOffice Calc typically uses the semi-colon rather than the comma as a list (i.e. *parameter*) separator. If you use the North American Excel standard of commas to separate the arguments in a function, you will receive:

```
508 Error:  Pair missing  For example, closing parenthesis without opening
                          parenthesis or missing closing parenthesis in the
                          middle of the formula (missing closing parenthesis
                          at the end of a formula is added automatically).
```

[image: SEMI-COLON 508 ERRORS]

Note that in B3 the `LEFT` function does not supply the *<number_of_characters>* parameter, deferring to the default of a single first character.

A full list of OpenOffice Calc error codes is available at: [Calc Error Codes](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes)

Comment: Well, thanks for using a link in my question to post an answer... Is this a joke or serious?

Comment: @TomášZato - I will often add superfluous information in a proposed solution to benefit future viewers of a Q&A thread since they may not have even read your original question. The link is merely a pointer to the official error code documentation. Maybe you should see where you went wrong and how I not only explained your mistake but noted that the parameter used in your example was wholly unnecessary. That is the primary information in the post; not [the link](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes).

Comment: Your answer looks nice and will likely help other visitors. But at the point of posting the question, I was aware of all information you provided. Therefore for me it's not helpful. Also, I was actually asking whether the Open Office can highlight/explain the problem in the particular entry - you can surely imagine that for larger formulas, the errors get quite unhelpful. Like having "`Syntax error`" for whole `.cpp` file...

Comment: * well, I wasn't aware that calc uses `;` as parameter separator, but I quickly found out.